# Cannot build your custom splash screen in your flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I added flutter launcher icons package and the respective dependencies.I have build drawer files and added the splash screen files in launch_background.xml file like this:

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/splash" />
    
    </item>

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_icon" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But I still have not shown the splash screen when starting my app.

I have put the min SDK version in my prok=ject/app/build.gradle to `21`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that if you are using minSdkVERSION to `greater` than or to `21` in your `project/app` root `build.gradle` file, then 2 launch_background.xml files are created. 1 is in the `drawable folder` and the other is in the `drawable-v21` folder. So you have to put the exact same code in both files. This worked for me.